# リセットボタンでcanvasに描いた線を消したい。

Tags: javascript, html, css

**前提**
アップロードか画像URLから画像を読み込み、表示し、画像にお絵描きができるツールを作っています。

[動作サンプル](https://jsbin.com/vokohexoxe/1/edit?html,js,output)

表示された画像をクリックするとパスを打つことができ、パスを3点以上打ってから1点目を打つとパスが閉じます。
パスを閉じた後の次のクリックは、リセットされ1点目になります。

**問題点**
リセットボタンを押すと画像が消えフォームの中身もクリアされますが、パスがクリアされません。
パスを打った後にリセットボタンを押し再度画像を読み込むと、リセット前に打ったパスが復活します。
なので、リセットボタンによってパスもクリアできるようにしたいです。

**使用ライブラリ**
・jQuery
・Paper.js

**ソースコード**

```js
$(function () {
  
  //リセットボタン
  $('#close').click(function () {
    $('#view').fadeOut();
    $('#url')[0].value = '';
    $('#file')[0].value = '';
    $('#pen').value = '';
  });
  
  $('#url').change(function () {
    $('#view').fadeOut(1);
    $('#file')[0].value = '';
    $('#view').fadeIn();
    input(this.value);
  });
  $('#file').change(function () {
    $('#view').fadeOut(1);
    $('#url')[0].value = '';
    $('#view').fadeIn();
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function (e) {
      input(e.target.result);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  });
  function input(e) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = draw;
    img.src = e;
  }
  function draw(e) {
    var img = e.target;
    var imgcnv = $('#img');
    var imgH = 800;
    var imgW = img.naturalWidth * imgH / img.naturalHeight;
    imgcnv.attr('width', imgW);
    imgcnv.attr('height', imgH);
    var ctx = imgcnv[0].getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgW, imgH);
    $('#img').width('100%');
    $('#img').height('100%');
    var penW = $('#img').width();
    var penH = $('#img').height();
    var pencnv = $('#pen');
    pencnv.attr('width', penW);
    pencnv.attr('height', penH);
    }
  });
```

```css
#view {
  display: none;
}
#draw {
  position: relative;
}
#img {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
#pen {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: crosshair;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.2/paper-full.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="url" type="text" placeholder="画像URLを貼付">
  <input id="file" type="file" accept="image/*">
  <div id="view">
    <div id="draw">
      <canvas id="img"></canvas>
      <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="pen">
        var hitOptions = Object.seal({
          segments: true,
          stroke: false,
          fill: false,
          tolerance: 10
        });
        var path = null;
        function onMouseDown(e) {
          var hitSeg = project.hitTest(e.point.clone(), hitOptions);
          var isClose = path != null
              && path.segments.length > 2
              && hitSeg
              && hitSeg.type === 'segment'
              && hitSeg.item.firstSegment === hitSeg.segment;
          if (isClose) {
            path.closed = true;
            path = null;
            return false;
          }
          if (path == null) {
            path = new Path();
            path.selected = true;
            path.add(e.point);
          }
          else {
            path.add(e.point);
          }
        } 
      </script>
      <canvas id="pen" width="720" height="600"></canvas>
    </div>
    <button id="close">リセット</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**試したこと**
paper.js及びpaperscriptの有無でパスを打てる機能のオンオフが切り替えられると考え、

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.2/paper-full.js"></script>

<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="pen">
```

画像を読み込んだタイミング上記2つのタグをで生成し、リセットボタンで上記2つのタグを消す、という処理をしてみました。
しかし、生成したタグではpaperscriptが機能せず、パスが打てませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

※ Paper.js は今始めて知ったものなので、間違っている箇所があるかもしれませんが、一応質問文の問題点が改善されたと思われるので、回答を残しておきます。

---

まず、リファレンスによれば、Path アイテムはアクティブなレイヤーの最上位に配置されます<sup>[[1]](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/project-items/project-hierarchy/#active-layer)</sup>。

> ### Active Layer<sup>[[1]](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/project-items/project-hierarchy/#active-layer)</sup>
>
> Each Paper.js Project starts out with one Layer which can be accessed through project.activeLayer. All newly created items are automatically added as a child of the layer which is currently active.

また、`Layer` クラスは `removeChildren` メソッドを実装しており、

> #### Hierarchy Operations<sup>[[2]](http://paperjs.org/reference/layer/#removechildren)</sup>
>
> **`removeChildren()`**
>   Removes all of the item’s children (if any).
>
> **Returns:**
>   Array of Item objects — an array containing the removed items

`Item` クラスを継承した `Group` クラスを継承している<sup>[[3]](http://paperjs.org/reference/layer/)</sup>ため、`hasChildren` メソッドが使用出来ます<sup>[[4]](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#haschildren)</sup>。

> ## Layer<sup>[[3]](http://paperjs.org/reference/layer/)</sup>
>
> Extends `Item`, `Group`
>
> The Layer item represents a layer in a Paper.js project.
>
> The layer which is currently active can be accessed through `project.activeLayer`. An array of all layers in a project can be accessed through `project.layers`.
>
> ---
>
> ## Item<sup>[[4]](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#haschildren)</sup>
>
> ### Hierarchy Tests
>
> **`hasChildren()`**
>   Checks if the item contains any children items.
>
> **Returns:**
>   Boolean — true it has one or more children, false otherwise

そして、paper オブジェクトのスコープは `PaperScope` クラスの `install` メソッドによってグローバルに注入出来ます<sup>[[5]](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/#install-scope)</sup>。

> ## PaperScope<sup>[[5]](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/#install-scope)</sup>
>
> ### Methods
>
> **`install(scope)`**
>   Injects the paper scope into any other given scope. Can be used for example to inject the currently active PaperScope into the window’s global scope, to emulate PaperScript-style globally accessible Paper classes and objects.
>
> **Please note:** Using this method may override native constructors (e.g. Path). This may cause problems when using Paper.js in conjunction with other libraries that rely on these constructors. Keep the library scoped if you encounter issues caused by this.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   scope:
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```js
> paper.install(window);
> ```

---

以上を用いて、以下のように JavaScript を変更することで、質問文の問題点は改善します。

```js
$(function() {
  //リセットボタン
  $('#reset').click(function() {
    $('#view').fadeOut();
    $('#url')[0].value = '';
    $('#file')[0].value = '';
    $('#pen').value = '';
    paper.project.activeLayer.removeChildren();
  });

  $('#url').change(function() {
    $('#view').fadeOut(1);
    $('#file')[0].value = '';
    $('#view').fadeIn();
    input(this.value);
  });
  $('#file').change(function() {
    $('#view').fadeOut(1);
    $('#url')[0].value = '';
    $('#view').fadeIn();
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e) {
      input(e.target.result);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  });

  function input(e) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = draw;
    img.src = e;
  }

  function draw(e) {
    var img = e.target;
    var imgcnv = $('#img');
    var imgH = 800;
    var imgW = img.naturalWidth * imgH / img.naturalHeight;
    imgcnv.attr('width', imgW);
    imgcnv.attr('height', imgH);
    var ctx = imgcnv[0].getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgW, imgH);
    $('#img').width('100%');
    $('#img').height('100%');
    var penW = $('#img').width();
    var penH = $('#img').height();
    var pencnv = $('#pen');
    pencnv.attr('width', penW);
    pencnv.attr('height', penH);
  }
});
```

```css
#view {
  display: none;
}

#draw {
  position: relative;
}

#img {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#pen {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: crosshair;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.2/paper-full.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="url" type="text" placeholder="画像URLを貼付">
  <input id="file" type="file" accept="image/*">
  <div id="view">
    <div id="draw">
      <canvas id="img"></canvas>
      <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="pen">
      paper.install(window);
      var hitOptions = Object.seal({
        segments: true,
        stroke: false,
        fill: false,
        tolerance: 10
      });
      var path = null;

      function onMouseDown(e) {
        var hitSeg = project.hitTest(e.point.clone(), hitOptions);
        var isClose = path != null && path.segments.length >
          2 && hitSeg && hitSeg.type === 'segment' && hitSeg.item.firstSegment === hitSeg.segment;
        if (isClose) {
          path.closed = true;
          path = null;
          return false;
        }
        if (path == null || !paper.project.activeLayer.hasChildren()) {
          path = new Path();
          path.selected = true;
          path.add(e.point);
        } else {
          path.add(e.point);
        }
      }
      </script>
      <canvas id="pen" width="720" height="600"></canvas>
    </div>
    <button id="reset">リセット</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```